# How can I connect to an HTTPS server using the Perl JIRA::Client::Automated module through Proxy?

Tags: perl, jira, cpan, jira-rest-api

I am new to use JIRA and REST API.Please tell me how to connect to HTTPS jira server using JIRA::Client::Automated module. I am trying to connect to jira server using below code.

```
use strict;
use warnings
use JIRA::Client::Automated;

my $user = 'foo';
my $pass = 'bar';
my $url = 'https://xxx.yyy';

my $jira = JIRA::Client::Automated->new($url, $user, $pass);
```

But using the above code always gives me an 500 error saying **Unable to connect**. Since I am trying to connect from my Local Machine, the request is not going through Local system proxy. Please let me know how to connect through Proxy.

Thanks for your Suggestion Daniel.
I have edited the code as per the your suggestion.

```
use strict;
use warnings
use JIRA::Client::Automated;

my $user = 'foo';
my $pass = 'bar';
my $url = 'https://xxx.yyy.com/jira-stage/';

my $jira = JIRA::Client::Automated->new($url, $user, $pass);
my $ua = $jira->ua();
$ua->proxy('http', 'http://proxy.com:8000');
$search_results = $jira->search_issues(project in (sample), 0, 1000);
my $count = $search_results->{'total'};
print "$count";
```

But still facing the same issue.Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the documentation of [`JIRA::Client::Automated`](https://metacpan.org/pod/JIRA::Client::Automated#ua). You can get the `LWP::UserAgent` object from it:

```
my $ua = $jira->ua;
```

Based on [`LWP::UserAgent`](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent#Proxy-attributes)'s documentation you can set the proxy like this

```
$ua->proxy('https', 'https://proxy:8080/');
```

or make it load the proxy settings from respective environment variables this way:

```
$ua->env_proxy;
```